# Derivating HEAD from Cached GET Requests using HTTPClient

Tags: java, httpclient, apache-httpcomponents

By specification `HEAD` responses shall be identical to `GET` responses except that their body must not be added to the response as stated on `HTTP/1.1` specification:

> The HEAD method is identical to GET except that the server MUST NOT return a message-body in the response. The metainformation contained in the HTTP headers in response to a HEAD request SHOULD be identical to the information sent in response to a GET request. This method can be used for obtaining metainformation about the entity implied by the request without transferring the entity-body itself. This method is often used for testing hypertext links for validity, accessibility, and recent modification.

Wouldn't it make sense to use an already cached `GET` request to generate the `HEAD` response?

Comment: What is the intent of the question? Have you check every framework out there if `HEAD` and `GET` are always separated? Why not reverse the case and [cache `HEAD` responses](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.2) and reuse them for `GET` responses which enrich the response with a payload body? To me this question is more related to [programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) anyway as this is more related towards concept than implementation

Comment: Sorry didn't get your comment, but the intention is to save round trips of `GET` after `HEAD` for specific resources. But I would say that already cached `GET`s may be used to provide `HEAD`s responses.

Comment: Well, technically you can just trim the body of a GET response to produce a HEAD response. The spec states that receiving an updated HEAD response may [invalidate or update a cached GET response](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7234#section-4.3.5). A HEAD response can therefore be used to check if the currently cached version of a GET response is still valid or not. If you directly extract the HEAD information from the cached GET response you will lose this feature IMO.